# Android.Manifest can't resolve symbol

Tags: android, android-studio

It seems like `android.Manifest` does not exist in any project I have or try to make. I have reinstalled android studio and various things but nothing seems to change pls help
Edit: I just found out that changing the compiled sdk version via the project structure to a lower version fix this error but create other error in dependencies. And I don't like this solution since I want to keep my compiled sdk version to 31.
[image]

Comment: I think you are missing the Android SDK. You can follow [this](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/setup-sdk).  Do you have a 'local.properties' file in your project which has a line something like this: 'sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\invissvenska\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk'. Otherwise you can try to set it up in Project Structure->SDK Location

Comment: I have android 12 sdk installed ( I verified in sdk manager), and I also have the 'local.properties' file with the correct path to the sdk file.

Answer (score 0):

So after trying a lot of things I just reinstalled windows, and now I don't have the issue on my project. Yeah, windows was the problem.